# Unmarshalling to same struct but different json name

Tags: json, go

I am trying to unmarshal a particular json data, perform some data transformations and then marshal the data and send it. However I want to marshal it with different json variable name.

Can I marshal the data to another json name like have xyz instead of abc

```
{"abc":1}
```

to

```
{"xyz":1}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
    SomeField   int         `json:"abc"`
}

func main(){
    jsonData := []byte(`{"abc":1}`)
    strct := SomeStruct{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &strct)
    fmt.Println(strct)
    x, err := json.Marshal(strct)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("errs", err)
    }
    finalValue := string(x)
    fmt.Println(finalValue)

    }
```

Comment: You will have to create another struct for this, with the json tag saying "xyz"

Comment: Thanks but is there any other way to do like using custom unmarshal or something?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3):

Define two structures, one for your input, one for your output, and convert like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type inStruct struct {
    SomeField   int         `json:"abc"`
}

type outStruct struct {
    SomeField   int         `json:"xyz"`
}

func main(){
    jsonData := []byte(`{"abc":1}`)
    strct := inStruct{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &strct); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Edit to reflect mkopriva's comment
    // outStruct := &outStruct{SomeField: strct.SomeField}
    outStruct := outStruct(strct)
    x, err := json.Marshal(outStruct)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    finalValue := string(x)
    fmt.Println(finalValue)
}
```

Comment: For ease of use, you can also create a function `func (i *inStruct) ToOutStruct() outStruct`

Comment: @AyushGupta that's not necessary, and neither is `&outStruct{SomeField: strct.SomeField}`. Since [Go 1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#language) you can convert structs with the same fields (regardless of their tags) directly.

Comment: @mkopriva that's much nicer, I didn't know, thanks!

Comment: The two structs need to have the same field names and types though. Too bad that does not work if the field names don't match. Like if the structures have the same field types in the same order, that could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially implement a custom `ToJSON` method for the struct, as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
    SomeField int `json:"abc"`
}

func (s *SomeStruct) ToJSON() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{\"xyz\":%d}", s.SomeField)
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"abc":1}`)
    strct := SomeStruct{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &strct)
    fmt.Println(strct)
    x, err := json.Marshal(strct)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("errs", err)
    }
    finalValue := string(x)
    fmt.Println(finalValue)
    fmt.Println("custom ToJSON", strct.ToJSON())

}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/mjW0dBPN59Q

It might not be flexible in the long run though. Personally, for requirement like this, I would prefer the solution posted by @Clément